# React: send keyed children to a component. Keys always null

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having a problem sending keyed elements to a child element which will filter those children by key. The idea is to map handlers to children by key, and the handlers will toggle the key to filter on.  I know using the index as key is an antipattern, but what is going on here? I always get the error `"Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

`render: function() {
    return (
      <Frame>
        <Frame>
          <Navbar isLoggedIn={true} handlers={this.handlers}>
            {this.props.children.map(function(child, i) {
              return (
                <button onClick={this.handlers[i]}>{child.props.text || 'Checkout item ' + i}</button>
              )
            }.bind(this))}
          </Navbar>
        </Frame>
        {this.props.isLoading
          ? <Loading />
        : <Filter
          filter={function(child) {
            return String(this.props.displayed) === child.key;
          }.bind(this)}>
          {this.props.children.map(function(child, i) {
            return (<div key={i}><child /></div>)
          })}
        </Filter>}
      </Frame>
    )
  }`

`function Filter (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Array.isArray(props)
      ? props.children.filter(function(child) {
          return props.filter(child);
        })
      : props.children}
    </div>
  )
};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a key to any DOM element being iterated. You are missing in `<button>`.

```
<Navbar isLoggedIn={true} handlers={this.handlers}>
  {this.props.children.map(function(child, i) {
    return (
      <button key={i} onClick={this.handlers[i]}>{child.props.text || 'Checkout item ' + i}</button>
    )
  }.bind(this))}
</Navbar>
```